# Google Maps Autocomplete: how to be more restrictive than country?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to make Google Map's autocomplete restrict results to, say, just within a state? It seems that it can only be restricted by country: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#ComponentRestrictions.

If there is no way to do it with Google's autocomplete, is there a jQuery plugin that will do this for me? I need a good autocomplete plugin that will hopefully return the entire map API response (or at least lat/lng vallues).

Comment: Have you resolved the original issue described in your question? It feels like we kind of left it hanging and I want to make sure you are good. Have you decided to keep moving forward with the Autocomplete?

Comment: Hi Sean, I still need to test the solution. Haven't had time. My feeling is that setting the bounds might work for me. Will keep you posted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the option of setting `bounds` rather than using `Component Restrictions` when you construct the `Autocomplete`. It is described in the [**Autocomplete section** of the Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_autocomplete) and coding specifications are defined in the [AutocompleteOptions entry in the API Doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#AutocompleteOptions). You may also change the bounds after the `Autocomplete` has been created by calling: `autocomplete.setBounds(bounds)`.

The `bounds` aren't guaranteed to limit results to results within the bounds, but setting the `bounds` to the area that covers a state or city will come very close to achieving what you describe.

If you need to go further, you also have the option of switching from the `Autocomplete` to using the Places Library[<sup>dev-guide</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places), which also allows you to define the `rankBy` optional property. If you use the `google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE` to define `rankBy`, you get added control over limiting the results returned to a specific geographic area. These are about the best options currently available on Google Maps.

Comment: Seems unnecessarily complex. Any non-Google solutions that may work for me?

Comment: It can feel complex, but when you consider the powerful options it gives you in a browser, it trades off as a winner. I don't know of anything that will give you exactly what you want in a pre-built widget. I've looked around at other options for mapping and related tools, but most of my hands-on has been with Google Maps, so it may be out there. The jQuery plugins offer some cool tooling, but they all run over the Google CDN, so they have to function (obviously) within the same scope of services. I'll be keeping an eye on this question; let's see what others have to say -

Comment: I'm new to Maps, so please bear with me. Since I am trying to get autocomplete to give me address of anything, I must use the type `geocode`, right? Your last suggestion means I should use the type `places`, which is not what I want, correct?

Comment: No sweat; I'm happy to help. Yes, if you want to restrict the results to addresses, use the `type`: `geocode`. My last suggestion is offered in case what I described in the previous paragraphs did not sound like it would meet your needs. It would mean dropping the `Autocomplete` and using the `Places Library` and it would require rolling up your sleeves and going deeper. If you feel like what I describe in the early part of the answer will work, I suggest using that option; it is simpler.